# How to change Font Color globally for the SWING application in Java

Tags: java, swing

I want to change the Font color to white for the entire application.How can I do it.

I was able to change the font using the following code

```
Enumeration keys=UIManager.getDefaults().keys();
    while(keys.hasMoreElements())
    {
        Object key=keys.nextElement();
        Object value=UIManager.get(key);
        if(value instanceof FontUIResource)
        {
            UIManager.put(key,font);
        }
    }
```

But what for color?

Answer (score 2):

> But what for color?

- this valuse is stored in key with `ColorUIResource` by default in `Xxx.foreground` or `XxxText`
- probably more, all of keys in @camickrs [UIManagerDefaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/)
- a.m. points aren't valid for Synth or Nimbus

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can provide a code snippet as I don't to mess up anything accidentally,as I am new to this portion.Thanks

Comment: @camickrs UIManagerDefaults has code that built GUI by reading UIManager, then question could be for why, why to reinvent the wheel